# How to output NLTK tabulate results into CSV?

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following:

```
fdist = FreqDist(text)
```

I want to output the following results of tabulate into a CSV (as opposed to python console).

```
fdist.tabulate()
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat `FreqDist` as a `dict`, and use the `csv` module.  For example:

```
from nltk import FreqDist
import csv

fdist = FreqDist("aaa b cccc dd e")

with open("fdist.csv", "wb") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(fdist.items())
```

produces

```
>>> !cat fdist.csv
" ","4"
"c","4"
"a","3"
"d","2"
"b","1"
"e","1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at (copy) [their source](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L259) and change the print statements as needed to write your CSV file. The source is copied below:

```
def tabulate(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    """ 
    Tabulate the given samples from the frequency distribution (cumulative), 
    displaying the most frequent sample first.  If an integer 
    parameter is supplied, stop after this many samples have been 
    plotted.  If two integer parameters m, n are supplied, plot a 
    subset of the samples, beginning with m and stopping at n-1. 
    (Requires Matplotlib to be installed.) 

    @param samples: The samples to plot (default is all samples) 
    @type samples: C{list} 
    """ 
    if len(args) == 0: 
       args = [len(self)] 
    samples = list(islice(self, *args)) 

    cumulative = _get_kwarg(kwargs, 'cumulative', False) 
    if cumulative: 
       freqs = list(self._cumulative_frequencies(samples)) 
    else: 
       freqs = [self[sample] for sample in samples] 
    # percents = [f * 100 for f in freqs]  only in ProbDist? 

    for i in range(len(samples)): 
       print "%4s" % str(samples[i]), 
    print 
    for i in range(len(samples)): 
       print "%4d" % freqs[i], 
    print
```